# calling number from a list to check if they are in a text file or not

Tags: list, python-3.x, csv

I have a text file which there are 3 numbers in each line.
I also have a list number, like : `lists = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`
I like to find the lines in a text file which all the 3 numbers are from the list. for example:
text file:

```
11 20 6
3 5 1
30 20 12
```

I want to find this line :`3 5 1`

What is the fastest way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `split()` and `set()`:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

with open('data.txt') as file:
    for i, line in enumerate(file):
        if(set(list(map(int, line.split()))).issubset(l)):
            print("Line %d has all numbers from the list" % i)
```

With an example file: `data.txt` like so:

```
11 20 6
3 5 1
30 20 12
```

**Output:**

```
Line 1 has all numbers from the list
```